# Riemann integral proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Prove that if the real valued function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ then so is $|f|$, and $|\int^b_a f(x)dx|\le \int^b_a |f(x)|dx$.

The definition I have for Riemann integral is: Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ $a<b$ and let $f$ be a real valued function on $[a,b]$. We say that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if there exists a number $A\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|S-A|<\epsilon$ whenever $S$ is Riemann sum for $f$ corresponding to any partition of $[a,b]$ of width less that $\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. To show that $|f|$ is integrable Riemann, it suffices to show that for every partition $P$ of $[a,b]$
$$
U(|f|,P)-L(|f|,P)\le U(f,P)-L(f,P),
$$
which in order to prove it suffices to show that, for every $[s,t]\subset [a,b]$
$$
\sup_{x,y\in[c,d]} |f(x)|-|f(y)|=
\sup_{x\in[c,d]}|f(x)|- \inf_{x\in[c,d]}|f(x)|\le 
\sup_{x\in[c,d]}f(x)- \inf_{x\in[c,d]}f(x)=\sup_{x,y\in[c,d]} f(x)-f(y),
$$
which is a consequence of the fact that
$$
\big| |f(x)|-|f(y)|\big|\le |f(x)-f(y)|.
$$

For the second part of the question, just use the fact that
$$
-|f(x)|\le f(x)\le |f(x)|
$$
and hence
$$
\int |f| \le \int f \le \int |f|
$$
and finally
$$
\Big|\int f\,\Big| \le \int|f|
$$

Comment: Yiorgos, why do you have variables $[s,t], [c,d]$ and $[x,y]$? I don't know what they specify?

Comment: @user104235: The $[c,d]$ correspond to the subintervals of the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint of part 1: Use the triangle inequality: //f(x)/ - /f(y)// < /f(x) - f(y)/ for x, y in [x(i), x(i+1)] which are two partition points of [a, b].